# pandas drop row if it is a subset of other row

Tags: python, pandas

I've searched around for quite a bit, but nothing seems to solve the issue.

Suppose when `df` is like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['a','b','c'], ['a',np.nan,'b'], [np.nan, 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'd', 'b']])
df
     0    1  2
0    a    b  c
1    a  NaN  b
2  NaN    b  a
3    a    d  b
```

Desired output is:

```
     0    1  2
0    a    b  c
3    a    d  b
```

Row 1, 2 are a subset of row 0, and hence I'd like to drop them. When checking if a row is a subset of any other, `NaN` is not considered. Thus row 1 becomes `{'a','b'}`, thereby a subset.

What I've tried so far is to make `set`s:

```
df.ffill(1).bfill(1).apply(set, 1)
```

which yields:

```
0    {c, a, b}
1       {a, b}
2       {a, b}
3    {d, a, b}
```

But I'm stuck here. `pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates` doesn't seem to help me here.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is tough.  Ideally you want to:

- Stick with Pandas vectorized operations rather than looping through rows.  (At first I thought of `pd.Index`, which behaves like a set and has some set-op-like methods.)
- Use hashtable-like data structures for set membership testing wherever possible.

Both of those things are tricky to do here because of the particular conditions, and the time complexity may get hairy as a result.  (I'm not ruling out that there's probably a much slicker answer than this one.)  But generally, once you go from exact-duplicate testing to subset testing, things become more difficult.

All that said, you can:

1. Convert DataFrame to a nested list - cut down on unncessary overhead with iterating over a Pandas data structure to the extent possible
2. Use `set.issuperset` in a greedy `any()` call to find indices of duplicates, taking advantage of the fact that `frozenset` is hashable (thanks to the other answer here).

The complexity is still N^2 or something close to it, but for moderate-sized data this might be sufficient.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['a','b','c'], ['a',np.nan,'b'], [np.nan, 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'd', 'b']])
>>> 
>>> seen = set()
>>> add = seen.add
>>> dupes = []
>>> 
>>> for pos, row in enumerate(df.values.tolist()):
...     vals = frozenset(i for i in row if isinstance(i, str))
...     if any(i.issuperset(vals) for i in seen):
...         dupes.append(pos)
...     add(vals)
... 
>>> dupes
[1, 2]
```

That gets you the indices to drop via `DataFrame.drop()`.

Comment: This solution given the right answer :-) (Not sure why deleted before:-)  )

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the great insight :)

Answer (score 2):

You might use `frozenset` instead of `set`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def remove_myself_from_dict(some_dict, myself):
    _some_dict = some_dict.copy()
    _ = _some_dict.pop(myself)
    return _some_dict

df = pd.DataFrame([['a','b','c'], ['a',np.nan,'b'], [np.nan, 't', 'a'], ['a', 'd', 'b']])
df['column_set'] = df.ffill(1).bfill(1).apply(frozenset, 1)

all_set = dict(zip(df['column_set'], range(len(df))))
df['is_subset'] = df['column_set'].apply(
    lambda x: any([some_set >= x for some_set in remove_myself_from_dict(all_set, x)])
)
```

The resulted `df` will be

```py
    0   1   2   column_set  is_subset
0   a   b   c   (b, c, a)   False
1   a   NaN b   (b, a)      True
2   NaN t   a   (t, a)      False
3   a   d   b   (b, d, a)   False
```

Comment: Thanks Bard. The frozenset is hashable because it is immutable, whereas set is mutable.

Comment: Seems not work for  `df = pd.DataFrame([['a','b','c'], ['a',np.nan,'b'], [np.nan, 't', 'a'], ['a', 'd', 'b']])`

Comment: @Wen-Ben, I added the data in the solution and tried again. It works as expected.

Comment: @ChunKitYeung you sure that is work with the data i listed above ? `pd.DataFrame([['a','b','c'], ['a',np.nan,'b'], [np.nan, 't', 'a'], ['a', 'd', 'b']])`

Comment: @Wen-Ben, Oh I see, I missed the `t` in the third row. Let me check about this.

Comment: As @Wen-Ben pointed out, this may not work in specific cases. Still +1 for great use of `frozenset` :)

Comment: @Wen-Ben, I have updated the solution. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Chris, thanks for your supporting. I have updated the solution. Hope this help too.